# How to approach writing antlr4 lexer for ambiguous grammar?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4

Suppose I have a grammar like:

```
grammar ambiguity;
activity : Action Sep Argument;
Action : [0-9];
Argument: [0-9];
Sep: ':';
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

The simple test is, say, "1:2";

The rule for Action and Argument is the "same", so the order of lexer fragments defines what is taken. When tokens are printed, it will be

```
Action, Action
and not
Action, Argument

Token: 1, Type: 1
Token: :, Type: 3
Token: 2, Type: 1
```

This output is expected since "Action" fragment is listed first. But is the logic of creating the grammar that I can't figure out how to handle. Should the grammar be written as:

```
activity : Val Sep Val;
fragment Val : [0-9];
```

and "Action", "Argument" parts be resolved in the code for listener? Please advise.

Comment: That is how I would do it, FWIW.

Comment: `Val` should not be a fragment though. Fragments can only be used in lexer rules.

Comment: Thank you, I reviewed  your latest comment and it makes sense for me now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is how to handle such cases in the lexer: make a single lexer rule and use that rule in parser rules. Note that `fragment` rules cannot be used in parser rules, so it should be:

```
activity : Val Sep Val;

Val : [0-9];
Sep: ':';
```

or:

```
activity : action Sep argument;

action : Val;
argument : Val;

Val : [0-9];
Sep: ':';
```

Comment: Aha! So you made two parser rules, and they in turn use a single lexer rule! That is what I think I was missing in my conceptual understanding of antlr4 product. Thank you, I will make a change and try your version.

Comment: Quick update - works as you explained it to me. Many thanks, Bart!

Comment: You're welcome @MichaelEstrinOne